# FCM + Flutter: how to add "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" to the notification payload when using sendMulticast?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm making an app with Flutter and Firebase. I'm creating a Firebase Function that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a notification to a user's devices (using `sendMulticast()`) when a document is created. It works fine, but I want to open a specific page in my app when the notification is clicked. Based on what I researched, to do that on Android I need to add `click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"` to the notification payload. However, when I add that, it stops working, and I get `{ success: false, error: [FirebaseMessagingError] }` as a response.

```
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


exports.sendNotificationToFCMToken = functions.firestore.document("chat_rooms/{chatRoomId}/messages/{messageId}")
.onCreate(async (snapshot: functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) => {

const senderUid: string = snapshot.data().sender_uid;
const recipientsUid: string[] = snapshot.data().recipients_uid;
const message: string = snapshot.data().message;

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();

recipientsUid.forEach(async (uid:string) => {

  const recipientTokensSnapshot = await db
    .collection("users_data")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("tokens")
    .get();

  const recipientTokens = recipientTokensSnapshot
    .docs.map((doc) => {
      console.log("doc.data().token: ", doc.data().token);
      return doc.data().token;
    });

  const notificationPayload = {
    notification: {
      title: senderUid,
      body: message,
      // clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", // If I add this line, it stops working
    },
    tokens: recipientTokens,
  };

  const response = await fcm.sendMulticast(notificationPayload);

  return;
});
```

});

How can I add `click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"` to the notification payload?

Comment: what error log you are getting in the cloud console? Try to get log details using functions.logger.log();

Comment: I don't get any specific/helpful errors in the console. When I log the output of the variable 'response' with console.log(response), I get the following: 

{
   sendNotificationToFCMToken:   responses: [ { success: false, error: [FirebaseMessagingError] } ],
   successCount: 0,
   failureCount: 1
}

Comment: Am I adding 'clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"' to the correct place by including it inside 'notification'? The docs are confusing. Some tutorials online place it in the same place that I did while others put it inside 'android' and 'notification', like this:
android: {
          notification: {
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          },
        }   I tried both variations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a payload that is currently running successfully at my end.

Consider using backticks **`** instead of single-quote **'** for the variables

```
const payLoad = {
            data: { 'type': 'Emergency Message' },
            notification: {
                title: `Emergency Message`, //Using backticks here
                body: `${data.message}`,//Using backticks here
                clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'//Using single quote here
            }
        };
```